# How to add Typescript to Cypress test?

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am struggling to write my Cypress test framework with TypeScript rather than JavaScript.
I have been following lots of online tutorials, but haven't been able to get it working properly.

In my `Login.ts` file below, I'm trying to create a variable, but I get this error `Cannot find name 'private'.ts(2304):` 
[image]

These are in my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^9.5.2",
    "tsify": "^5.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using private in the correct way. This can only be used for member declarations in a class.

you need to use

```
let accountBalance: number = 0
```

to use a private member var you would do

```
class user {
   private _accountBalance : number;

   constructor( ) {

   }

   // Would only include this if you want to be able to set it from externally
   set accountBalance( value : number ) {
       this._accountBalance = value;
   }

   // Would only include this if you wanted to get the balance externally
   get accountBalance() : number {
      return this._accountBalance;
   }
}
```